# ¿Cómo redireccionar una página a otra?

Tags: php, html, mysql

En mi proyecto tengo tres archivos "Landing-page.php" · "Login.php" · "Dashboard.php" y lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente...

si soy un usuario nuevo me lleve a landing-page.php, y si inicio sesión me lleve a dashboard.php.
ahora bien, si me salgo de la página ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) sin haber cerrado sesión y abra nuevamente la página me redireccione a dashboard.php. pero si cierro sesión y salga de la página y entre nuevamente a la página, me redireccione a landing-page.php.

cabe recalcar que dashboard.php redirecciona a login.php si un usuario intenta ingresar sin haber iniciado sesión.

espero haber sido lo más claro posible

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código que tengas hecho hasta ahora ?. Primero tienes que tener claro que si vas a trabajar con sesiones en PHP, solo se puede mantener una sesión mientras que la ventana del navegador esté abierta. Si cierras la ventana, la sesión se pierde y luego será como un nuevo usuario. Si que persistirá la sesión si se cierra la pestaña, pero una vez que cierres la ventana del navegador, se pierde si o si

Answer (score 1):

Primero deberías asignar al usuario que se loguea a una variable SESSION en tu clase login ($_SESSION['user'] = $usuario), luego en una clase llamada isLogin, o algo por el estilo, llamar a session_start() y obtener el usuario con $usuario = $_SESSION['user'], comprobar con un if(isset($usuario)) para saber si me devuelve el usuario, cuando sea true ir directo al dashboard, cuando sea false ir directo a la landing page.
Así cuando sea un usuario nuevo lo va a dirigir a la landing page porque me devuelve false, igual si se cierra sesión devuelve false, cuando salgo de la página sin cerrar sesión devuelve true y dirige al dashboard.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Soy nuevo en PHP, tienes algún tutorial acerca de esto? gracias de antemano.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZTJYCAMsOc8

Comment: gracias, esto me ayudará